# Doubt regarding definition of proposition

Tags: logic, definition

The definition of a **proposition** is as follows

> A proposition is a declarative statement that is either true or false
>   but not both

Let us categorize declarative statement in to four types

**Type 1:** True declarative statements

Ex: 2 + 3 = 5

**Type 2:** False declarative statement

Ex: 2 * 3 = 5

**Type 3:** Dual declarative statement (both true and false)

Ex: x + 2 = 5

**Type 4:** Declarative statement that is neither true nor false

My doubt is whether **type 4 exists or not**? Does type 4 comes under **paradox**? Are both(type 4 and paradox) same? Are the following paradoxes come under type 4?

**This statement is false.**

**I know that i know nothing**

If not, provide an example for type 4?

Comment: Type 3 does not exist; see your def: " a declarative statement that is either true or false **but not both**".

Comment: True, In question, the example I wrote under type 3 has to be under type 4.

Comment: I suggest replacing "a declarative statement that is either true or false but not both" with "a well-formed formula in a logical system with no free variables"...

Comment: It seems like you're saying a statement is true when it's true for some assignment of free variables, and false when it's false for some assignment of free variables. Using this definition, a statement in 1st-order logic must be either true or false or both.

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of such statements. Generally, ill-defined statements fall under the category of: 'neither true nor false'.

For example, consider this statement: $$\text{This ice-cream is tasty} $$ This cannot be true or false without an appropriate definition of "tasty" as applied to "the icecream." And yes, your first example statement also falls under this category.

Also, see [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-statements-that-are-neither-true-nor-false), and these previous MSE questions:

- [Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088147/is-a-paradox-a-truth-value)
- [Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048256/if-something-is-neither-true-nor-false-what-is-it)

Comment: How "This ice-cream is tasty" doesn't come under type 3? x+2 = 5 and its truth value depends on x. Here taste can be considered as x, which can vary in a set of people?

Comment: See @Mauro's comment, sir. Those type of statements are not propositions.